# apply display none property of css on a paragraph

Tags: css

i am working on css and i want to display none the p tag width refrence of div class ""abc but unable to do so i also cannot put and class in p tag as its auto generating so the use of refrence is must but in correct way. any help please.

here is the html:

```
<div class="abc">any text</div>
<p>any text here</p>
```

here is the css i tried so far:

```
.abc p{ display:none}
```

but i know its not correct i also search it on google but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`.  It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element:

```
.abc + p{ display:none}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZejXS/)**

Comment: The `+` is valid all the way back to IE7. Does your page have a valid doctype? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358818%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For that CSS to work, you need to contain your paragraph within your div:

```
<div class="abc"><p>any text here</p></div>
```

Or given your markup, the sibling selector:

```
.abc + p { display:none }
```